# Android: Rotate and display image from file

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I have a very simple layout with an ImageView.  My application opens the camera, saves an image, and then displays the image in the ImageView with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`.  The only issue is that it's rotated.  I understand that a) this is due to the phone's camera defaulting to landscape, so this needs to be handled in code and b) image processing must be done in a separate thread from the UI.

The Android training documentation seems to be geared toward loading images from resource id's instead of file paths.  This just throws a wrench in things as I'm able to follow the tutorials up to a point but ultimately have trouble reconciling the differences.

I'm certainly new at this so if someone could just give me a high-level overview of what needs to be done to accomplish this, I'd really appreciate it.  The following code is where I'm currently adding the bitmap to the ImageView.  I assume that my call to the separate thread would go in `onCreate`?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MainActivity.image_path);

    displayImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

    displayImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: So you want to only rotate the Image?

Comment: Correct.  The ImageView itself is properly oriented.  It's just that the image inside it is always displayed 90 degrees counter-clockwise.  The file, however, is oriented properly so I just need to rotate it for the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) for rotate

```
picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
switch (orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    matrix.postRotate(270);
    break;
default:
    break;
}

myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
```

**Note :** Here `picturePath` is selected *Image's* path from `Gallery`

- [***tutorial***](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.media.ExifInterface)

Comment: This is working but it raises one additional issue that I just want to confirm.  I'm doing this in a separate thread so I can't actually render the bitmap until `onPostExecute`.  Again - it's working great but I just want to be sure that this isn't creating an additional bitmap when passed into `onPostExecute`.  So I understand, Java is only passing a _reference_, so the entire process really only creates one bitmap.  Is this correct?

Comment: instead of passing the bitmap pass `picturePath` and processed the bitmap in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: `onPostExecute` is run on the UI thread, though.  It's entirely possible that I have an incorrect understanding of this but I was under the impression that all bitmap processes needed to be completed in a non-UI thread.  It did just dawn on me, however, that I'm only loading a scaled version of the bitmap and it's being loaded from memory - not over the network or anything.  Would this be ok to complete in the UI thread as long as I'm not loading the entire, unscaled image?

Comment: move the code into `onActivityResult(...)` and no need of `scaled` *bitmap*

Comment: Still getting the hang of the device monitor but it did seem that there were some memory savings using a sampled image as opposed to unsampled.  The file is generated by the camera so the original bitmap is fairly large.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working with the following approach.  I think you could do this without the AsyncTask but it seems that best practice states you should perform image processing in a non-UI thread (please feel free to correct - I'm quite new at this).

An improvement which could be made to this would be to handle the scaling in a more granular way.  `inSampleSize` is a great tool but it will only scale by powers of 2.  Another improvement would be to initially only read the meta/EXIF data into `bmOriginal` as the only use of this variable is to retrieve the height and width.

ImageView XML - pretty much standard.  android:layout_width/height set to `fill_parent`.

From the activity's java file -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);

    new ImageRotator().execute(MainActivity.image_path);
}

private class ImageRotator extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... image_path){

        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bmOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path[0], bitmapOptions);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.postRotate(90);

        bmOriginal = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmOriginal, 0, 0, bmOriginal.getWidth(), bmOriginal.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        return bmOriginal;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        myImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

The scaling process was found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12cB7gnL6po&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc86y1CjAlexivfvOms6_0NC&index=1) and there's a great explanation of AsyncTask's features [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Thanks so much to all who responded and again - please feel free to let me know if this is way off base or even if there's just a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother to rotate the image. As you said "The ImageView itself is properly oriented. It's just that the image inside it is always displayed 90 degrees counter-clockwise. " , then just
make the ImageView rotate 90 degrees clockwise, the image will display correctly.

```
    displayImageView.setRotation(90);
```

Comment: This does properly orient the image but now there's a lot of white space around it.  My android:layout_width/height are set to fill_parent.  It seems that the height of the final ImageView is the width of my display.  I'm assuming that the rotate happens after the activity creates the view.  Is there a way to "refresh" this and have it re-apply fill_parent?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2864874 Can you post a screenshot in your original question?

Comment: @user2864874  If you set the ImageView's layout_height/width fill/match_parent, the space outside of the image should be transparent. The white space you mentioned should be the color of the underground view. Maybe you need to scale the ImageView to fill the space?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate an image using a matrix or set the rotation in your xml. If you want more control however, you can check out this tutorial written for rotating images and saving to disk:

[How to rotate an image in android](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-rotate-an-image-in-android/)

I hope that helped.