# Is there any method to display landscape image in portrait mode selected from gallery or taken from camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm displaying image selected from gallery or taken from camera in an Image View. What can I do so that image displayed in the image view is in portrait mode irrespective of the original form of the image ?

This is for creating an activity that will set user profile picture by selecting from gallery or from camera. The following code snippet is the function where I am setting the image view with the image selected from gallery or camera. I am not getting  how to find orientation of the image in the `onActivityResult()` function so that I can rotate it to portrait mode before displaying.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   switch(requestCode){
       case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
               try {
                   bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
               iv.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
           }
           break;
       case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
           if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
               Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
               bitmap=(Bitmap)  extras.get("data");
               iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           }
   }
```

Comment: check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598027/android-rotate-and-display-image-from-file

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but there is one issue. It works fine for images taken from gallery, but not for the image clicked from the camera as its not stored. Any other solution you could suggest

Comment: The thumbnail returned in `extras.get("data")` may be too small even for your phone screen

Comment: @Nandan -  share your camera capture code, and whenever you capture code you can get image path.